# Projects cannot run in eclipse because of deleting the whole .metadata folder by mistake

Tags: eclipse

I delete the whole .metadata folder by mistake, so my projects in eclipse cannot run at all, and there is no backup for .metadata folder. what should I do to fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to re-import it?

Comment: I mean, I just delete it completely from my disk.

Comment: No i mean, delete the project from your workspace. Don't delete the project on your disk! And then import the project from code

Comment: The safest way would be to unzip Eclipse to a new directory, and then import your projects one at a time until you've restored your development environment.

Comment: YES! I've fixed it by unzipping. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have too many projects you could do this:

1. Open eclipse with the same workspace as before.
2. Create a new project with the exact same name and working directory as your previous project.

Repeat step 2 for each project.

Eclipse will find the files, but if you had any additional settings you might have to add them manually.