# Scala: what are .metadata files and can I ignore them in my version control?

Tags: git, scala

I do not see .metadata files listed in [GitHub's Scala.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Scala.gitignore), but I am not sure what they do or why there are so many of them. Can I ignore them in my repo and still have my Scala projects port fine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen those in my Scala projects.  Are you using sbt, play, etc?

Comment: You're using Eclipse, right?

Comment: Yeah, this is for Odersky's Coursera course on Scala, so I am using Eclipse and sbt as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files you're seeing do not relate to Scala nor it's direct ecosystem (play, sbt). They are related to Eclipse internings. If you used to storing pure source code (without any IDE information) you can safely ignore them (put a record in .gitignore). Sadly, looks like [Eclipse can't function properly without them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15503869/298389).

P.S. note that course Honor Code disallows you to push solutions code to freely accessible places (like Github **public** repositories)

Comment: So it seems like I should not ignore them if I want to use Eclipse in multiple environments (home, work, etc)?

Comment: It's quite open question. Nothing stops you from having local .metadata on home, work, ... machines (if you're not lazy enough to configure Eclipse for every environment ;-) ). But since it's your own code and project is not shared between team members (who might prefer IDEA, or Sublime or different Eclipse configuration) -- you could store Eclipse files in VCS -- why not?